# Spring Data Jpa TO Dynamically Set JSON_CONTAIN Literral

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

`update team set  PRODUCT_SUB_PRODUCT=JSON_REMOVE(PRODUCT_SUB_PRODUCT,JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(PRODUCT_SUB_PRODUCT, 'all', \"?3\" ))) where tenant = ?1 and  BUSINESS_UNIT_ID = ?2 and" JSON_CONTAINS(PRODUCT_SUB_PRODUCT,'{\"product\": \"?3\"}')`

my method Has 3 parms
void removeProduct(Long tenant,Long buId, Long productId);

output : update
team_business_unit_association
set
PRODUCT_SUB_PRODUCT=JSON_REMOVE(PRODUCT_SUB_PRODUCT,
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(PRODUCT_SUB_PRODUCT,
'all',
"?3" )))
where
tenant = ?
and  BU_ID = ?
and JSON_CONTAINS(PRODUCT_SUB_PRODUCT,'{"product": "?3"}');

and the Binding params are only two
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [221]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1194]

it is not considering the 3rd param which is product id

SCEMA IN DB:
`[{"product": "30485", "subProduct": [], "accessOnAllSubProdcut": false}]`

i tried using named parameters but that also did not work